# Dexie Table.update() behaves like Table.put()

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a bit of code:

```
db.files.update(id, {name: name}).then(function(updated) {
    // Other stuff
}
```

When it runs, it replaces the entire record with

```
{
    name: "File name"
}
```

According to [the docs](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.update().html), this is what Table.put() should do, not Table.update().

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a problem with Dexie?

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve] that shows how you initialize the database, how you perform the update, and how you check your values afterwards.

Comment: @Louis, sorry about that. I realized that I was accessing an array of data pulled from the Dexie database that wasn't properly setting all the data when it was initialized. As I suspected, it was my own problem.